# MongoDB-7.0.0 "ErrMsg" : "Client sent an HTTP request over a native MongoDB connection"

Tags: mongodb

When I first started MongoDB, I installed it on Windows and ran mongod.exe. It seems to keep running in cmd with dbpath input, but when I connect to localhost:27017, it says it can't connect.
I'm guessing it's probably because it's blocked by the firewall or the certificate isn't installed, but is there any way to fix this?

The output from cmd after execution is as follows.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:29.490+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":21},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:29.491+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.412+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.413+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.413+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.413+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.413+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":7091600, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Starting TenantMigrationAccessBlockerRegistry"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.414+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":15336,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/Users/ypwa1/mongodb-7.0.0/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Xavier"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.414+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.414+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"7.0.0","gitVersion":"37d84072b5c5b9fd723db5fa133fb202ad2317f1","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.414+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 22621)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.414+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"C:\\Users\\ypwa1\\mongodb-7.0.0\\data\\db"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.415+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/Users/ypwa1/mongodb-7.0.0/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.416+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=15844M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.711+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":295}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.711+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.715+09:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.715+09:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.717+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":21},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":21,"maxWireVersion":21},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":21,"maxWireVersion":21},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.717+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5853300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"current featureCompatibilityVersion value","attr":{"featureCompatibilityVersion":"7.0","context":"startup"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.718+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.718+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6608200, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing cluster server parameters from disk"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.718+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.941+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/Users/ypwa1/mongodb-7.0.0/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.943+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.943+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.944+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:30.944+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:40.999+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53961","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"4151665c-87ef-4366-8900-f8dfdc582912"}},"connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:41.000+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53962","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"4ce19519-6c56-4e55-864a-ce7f883cc21a"}},"connectionId":2,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:41.005+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":17,"codeName":"ProtocolError","errmsg":"Client sent an HTTP request over a native MongoDB connection"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:53961","connectionId":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:41.006+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53961","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"4151665c-87ef-4366-8900-f8dfdc582912"}},"connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:41.256+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53964","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"912c120e-73db-4c5b-972a-2d0a451569f3"}},"connectionId":3,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:42.035+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":17,"codeName":"ProtocolError","errmsg":"Client sent an HTTP request over a native MongoDB connection"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:53962","connectionId":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:42.035+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53962","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"4ce19519-6c56-4e55-864a-ce7f883cc21a"}},"connectionId":2,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:42.040+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":17,"codeName":"ProtocolError","errmsg":"Client sent an HTTP request over a native MongoDB connection"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:53964","connectionId":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:42.040+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53964","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"912c120e-73db-4c5b-972a-2d0a451569f3"}},"connectionId":3,"connectionCount":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:42.355+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53967","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"a5c4bdec-d56c-48f8-8a38-677d813e60dc"}},"connectionId":4,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:42.359+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":17,"codeName":"ProtocolError","errmsg":"Client sent an HTTP request over a native MongoDB connection"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:53967","connectionId":4}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:42.359+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53967","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"a5c4bdec-d56c-48f8-8a38-677d813e60dc"}},"connectionId":4,"connectionCount":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:42.608+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53968","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"235a68d8-f875-46ac-8f26-815b05bc212c"}},"connectionId":5,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:47.384+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":17,"codeName":"ProtocolError","errmsg":"Client sent an HTTP request over a native MongoDB connection"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:53968","connectionId":5}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:47.385+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53968","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"235a68d8-f875-46ac-8f26-815b05bc212c"}},"connectionId":5,"connectionCount":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:47.688+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53971","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"8dfb6ed3-b821-4c6b-ae1b-e08c834a4536"}},"connectionId":6,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:47.692+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":17,"codeName":"ProtocolError","errmsg":"Client sent an HTTP request over a native MongoDB connection"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:53971","connectionId":6}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-31T22:32:47.692+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:53971","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"8dfb6ed3-b821-4c6b-ae1b-e08c834a4536"}},"connectionId":6,"connectionCount":0}}
```

I've tried search google, but I couldn't find solution..

Comment: "_when I connect to localhost:27017_" - like in the browser? There's no built-in interface like that. You connect to the database via drivers in your app. If you want a GUI tool for management, try Studio3T or Compass

Comment: Are you trying to open `127.0.0.1:27017` in the browser? That is not a HTTP Server, its a TCP socket used for the MongoDB Wire Protocol (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/) which is used by client libs to communicate with the database server.

Comment: When you connect to your localhost, then there is no firewall in between. And you did not configure any certificates, so this cannot be the problem either.

Comment: Thank you! So, can we just understand that the difference between connecting to localhost:27017 in the browser and connecting through Studio3T lies in the protocol?